# Solving $ f(k) = f(k−1 ) + 2f(k−2) + 2^k $ where $f(0)=4 ,f(1)=12$

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to solve $ f(k) = f(k−1 ) + 2f(k−2) + 2^k $ where $f(0)=4 ,f(1)=12$. I first get the following homogenous part

$$(r+1)(r-2)=0$$ where $$ r_{1}=-1 \text{ and } r_{2}=2 $$ then I get the homogenous part as
$$ (-1)^k . C_{1} + 2^k . C_{2} $$

For the partial part, I try to do the following.

$$f_{partial}(k) = A.2^k.k \text {  , times $k$ because $2^k$ is in homogenous solution} \\
f_{partial}(k-1) = A.2^{(k-1)}.(k-1) \\
f_{partial}(k-2) = A.2^{(k-2)}.(k-2)
$$

To solve it, I write it as follows.

$$A \cdot 2^k \cdot k=\frac{A \cdot 2^k \cdot(k-1)}{2}+\frac{2 \cdot A \cdot 2^k \cdot(k-2)}{4}+2^k \\ 
\Rightarrow A = \frac{2}{3}$$

Then I find $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$,

$$C_{1}+C_{2}= 4 \\ -C_{1}+2C_{2}+\frac{4}{3}= 12 \\ \Rightarrow C_{2} = \frac{44}{9} \\ \Rightarrow C_{1} = -\frac{8}{9}$$

When we sum all up,

$$2^k \cdot \frac{44}{9}-\frac{8}{9} \cdot(-1)^k+\frac{2}{3} \cdot 2^k \cdot k$$

However, it seems wrong because the solution book says
$$a_k=\frac{38}{9} \cdot 2^k+\frac{2}{3} \cdot(k+1) 2^k-\frac{8}{9} \cdot(-1)^k$$

Where is my wrong? Can you help, please?

Comment: The sequence is https://oeis.org/A291023 starting at the 3rd term.

Comment: @R.J.Mathar what should I understand from this?

Comment: The generic theory of solving inhomogeneous recurrences with constant coefficients is explained in https://www2.mpia-hd.mpg.de/homes/mathar/public/mathar20071126.pdf

Comment: Your solution is the same as the one in the book

Comment: @DominikKutek how?

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire add and subtract $\frac{2}{3}2^x$ or just subtract both answers and check